# Importing parts of a .txt file in LaTeX document

Tags: verbatim, input, sourcecode

Can you define which lines and columns from a .txt file to show up in LaTeX?
I tried the \lstinputlisting command where it seems I can only limit the output to specific lines and not columns as well, like in
\lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=1]{filename.txt}
My aim is to only have to change the text in .txt file values in specific places so that I can easily keep my output updated.
Is there a way to include columns in the \lstinputlisting command or is there another way to define specific text passages from .txt file?

Comment: I'm almost sure, there are other duplicates, e.g., for another verbatim package instead of `listings`. But as long a your question is absolutely unclear and as long a you don't show a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) showing, why `listings` cannot be use, it IMHO does not make much sense to search for one, because I would suggest to use `listings`.

Comment: The duplicate is not for `\input`. AFAIK there isn't any solution to input (and interpret) only some lines of a tex file.

Comment: @cabohah Thanks, that helped. Still too new to comment on their thread, but maybe you know: Is it possible to add columns to this line? I couldn't make it work with listings.

\lstinputlisting[firstline=,lastline=]{filename.txt}

Comment: Columns in which respect? Sorry, your question is still unclear. So please ask a follow-up question with more information and [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), or at least edit your question to add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) and explain your problem. BTW: `firstline` and `lastline` expect a value (e.g. `firstline=5,lastline=10` see also the examples on the linked page and the `listings` user manual).

Comment: A minimal working example would be nice, but even without it the question is reasonably clear in my opinion. Columns are the (character) positions in a line, for example the (currently non-existing) syntax `firstline=1:5, lastline=2:10` would select a 'block' of 2x5 characters from the middle of line 1 and 2. Or maybe a simpler version where only the columns on a single line can be given, (also nonexisting) `line=3:5:10` for characters 5-10 on line 3.

Comment: @Marijn That's exactly what I meant, thanks.